# Javascript auto convert certain text to labels like style

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, label, text-editor

On some websites there are text editors in which you type things like {{first_name}} then it gets converted to something like this [image]

They also offer a dropdown clicking on that First Name label. Are there any Javascript libraries that make such a process easy?

Answer (score 0):

I dont Know Of any js libaries for this but with vannila js it should go like this.

To Convert The Text To A Label A Simple Function Should Work Like This.

```
function changetheLabel() {
        let label = document.getElementById('your id');
        let text= document.getElementById('your id').value;

        label.innerText = empName;       
    }
```

Its Not Specified What Kind Of dropdown with what info.

if you have some html you could add to your post i could maybe help more.